# Swift - Type has no member

Tags: swift, class, static-methods, public, subclassing

I have a basic class named `APIGroup` that exists for the sole purpose of subclassing (it is not [yet] used for anything but certain `static` properties that are accessed by the subclasses). It looks somewhat like this:

```swift
public class APIGroup {
    public static let someProperty : String = "I am a property!"
}
```

And I have a subclass, `Track`, which defines a *type* method `search` as follows:

```swift
public class Track : APIGroup {
    public static func search(name: String) -> Void {
        print("Track search initiated. Name: \(name)")
        print("And the property is: \(someProperty)")
    }
}
```

These two classes are defined in separate files in the same module. In another target, I import the module and try to call:

```swift
import MyModule

MyModule.Track.search("testing...")
```

But this throws: `Type 'Track' has no member 'search'`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add the file containing this method to the target you are testing? (i.e. in Xcode you have to check the box under Target Membership in the File inspector so that the file is included as part of the target)

Comment: Yes, I did. I can access `MyModule` and `MyModule.Track`.

Comment: @Sulthan If only coding were that simple...

Comment: Could there be a name collision with another class `Track`?

Answer (score 0):

Putting this code in a Playground works fine for me:

```
import Foundation

public class APIGroup {
    public static let someProperty : String = "I am a property!"
}

public class Track : APIGroup {
    public static func search(name: String) -> Void {
        print("Track search initiated. Name: \(name)")
        print("And the property is: \(someProperty)")
    }
}

Track.search("testing...")
```

If they are in the same module you do not need to import or use the module name.

[image]

Comment: It works for me, too, but see what I said about the different files/modules.

Comment: Actually, it just randomly started working. I didn't even change everything, I just tried recompiling a few hours later. Thanks for the help, though!