# Why am I getting has no member error

Tags: swift, unit-testing

Sorry if this is an easy one, but I'm spinning up on Swift 3 and I'm just stuck.

I created my Swift 3 class and a unit test for it. I'm now adding a new method and want to write a unit test for it:

```
public func isEmpty() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Then I went to my unit test and wrote the following:

```
func testPersist() {
    XCTAssertFalse(currentQuote.isEmpty())
}
```

But the assert gets an error saying: `Value of type CurrentQuote has no member 'isEmpty'`

I found these questions, but they don't seem to help me:

[Swift - Type has no member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355179/swift-type-has-no-member)
["classname has no member functionname" when adding UIButton target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673261/classname-has-no-member-functionname-when-adding-uibutton-target)

I'm sure this is something basic, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Where did you define `isEmpty()`? Is it within the definition of `CurrentQuote`?

Comment: try to remove your unit test from build and use it only in debug

Comment: @Luke It is within the definition of CurrentQuote.

Comment: @RinaLiu I have no idea what you're trying to tell me.

Comment: is the `CurrentQuote` class also marked `public`?  e.g. `public class CurrentQuote { ... }`, or you could try `@testable import <Project that contains CurrentQuote>` in your unit test file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a timing error. I ran the test to force a build and it ran fine. I think the executable hadn't been updated since I added the method and it was still showing as missing.